# Is pushing a variable onto an array a threadsafe operation?

Tags: perl, multithreading, thread-safety, reentrancy

I have the following Perl code:

```
push(@myArray, $myValue);
```

Is the operation atomic, or will I need to use locks, if multiple threads will be performing this same operation on many threads?

Comment: Seems you want a Thrread::Queue object.

Comment: What do you mean 'same operation'? Is @myArray shared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread safety of most functions in perl depends on their underlying C routines, and in the case of built-ins, like `push` there is no mention of thread safety, so you must assume it is not.

Check out the `perlthrtut` man page, in particular the section titled "Basic Semaphores".  Using a semaphore you can enforce mutual exclusion in arbitrary sections of code.